# Creating a dataframe from a dictionary of irregular size in julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I would like to know, how may I create a DataFrame from a dictionary of irregular size?

I have created a small snippet to achieve this operation:

```
using DataFrames
d = Dict(:a => rand(10), :b => rand(50), :c => rand(40))
df = DataFrame()

for (key, values) in d 
    x = string(key)
    val = d[key]
    df[!, x] = val
end

println(df)
```

But upon execution the following error is displayed:

```
ArgumentError: New columns must have the same length as old columns
```

Please suggest the correct syntax to perform such operation.

Thanks!

Comment: In data frame all columns are required to have the same number of rows. What number of rows would you expect in the result of this operation then: 10 (truncation), 50 (expansion), or 200 (repeating to LCM)? If you want 50 (expansion), then what values you want to be used to fill missing values?

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński thanks for the response, I wanted to go with expansion. The goal is to check the `keys` in `dictionary` for maximum number of values and for this the size of the dataframe is to be set. Whereas to fill the missing values with `missing` which i can work with during post-processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the shortest way to do it:

```
select(outerjoin(map(collect(d)) do v
                     d = DataFrame(v)
                     insertcols!(d, 1, :id => axes(d, 1))
                 end..., on=:id), Not(:id))
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
function helper(x, n)
    v = missings(eltype(x), n)
    v[axes(x, 1)] = x
    return v
end
n = maximum(length.(values(d)))
df = DataFrame()
for (c, v) in d
    df[!, c] = helper(v, n)
end
df
```

but it is a bit more complex and low-level.